# Identify the shrub

Tags: identification, shrubs

Please help me identify the bush?  this looks like Spirea cantoniensis but the flower is different
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a Deutzia variety, most likely D. scabra. Your photo does not magnify well so I can't see the flowers clearly, but a variety of D. scabra is pictured [here](https://www.burncoose.co.uk/site/plants.cfm?pl_id=1533).

If this Deutzia does not have pink tinges anywhere, it won't be that particular variety, but Deutzia it is nonetheless.